# BadMethodCallException Method [logout] does not exist

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('admin/manager/logout','Admin\IndexController@logout');
```

**ManagerController:**

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    return redirect('/admin/manager/login');
}
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
<li>
    <a href="/admin/manager/logout" onclick="if(!confirm('Confirm exit?')){ return false }">Log out</a>
</li>
```

**ERROR:**

> **(1/1) BadMethodCallException Method [logout] does not exist.**

Comment: the controller name is ManagerController but in route you are passing IndexController?? doesnt seem correct or you mispelled the controller?

Comment: it is very unclear what you are asking, try provide more info on what you try to do.

Comment: You are probably calling method logout() on the Admin/IndexController or some wrong controller. Check your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `logout` method defined in `ManagerController` so in route change it:

```
Route::get('admin/manager/logout','Admin\ManagerController@logout');
```